# ReactJS - Children do not re-render correctly after change in parent

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, parent, children

I am new to ReactJS, so I tried to develop a little application to understand how it works. It is an interface which grab data (users) from an API, and display it. I can also add data and delete users. Adding is working but I have issues with deleting.

Json Component (Parent)

```
class Json extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {items: []}
    this.updateDelete = this.updateDelete.bind(this)
    this.updateAdd = this.updateAdd.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.grabusers();
  }

  grabusers() {
    var request = new Request('http://localhost:4000/users', {
         method: 'GET',
         mode: 'cors'
    });
    fetch(request).then(result=>result.json()).then(items=>this.setState({items: items}))
  }

  updateDelete(user){
    var i = this.state.items.indexOf(user)
    var items = this.state.items
    items.splice(i,1)
    this.setState({items: items})
  }

  updateAdd(user){
    var items = this.state.items
    items.push(user)
    this.setState(items)
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Form updateJson={this.updateAdd}/>
        <div className="row">
          {this.state.items.map(item => <Card item={item} updateJson={this.updateDelete}/>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Card Component (Child)

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {item: props.item}
    this.delete = this.delete.bind(this)
  }

  delete(){
    var request = new Request('http://localhost:4000/users/'+this.state.item._id, {
         method: 'DELETE',
         mode: 'cors'
    });
    fetch(request).then(() => this.props.updateJson(this.state.item))
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="col-md-4">
      <div className="Card row">
        <div className="col-md-2"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
        <div className="col-md-10"><Fullname firstname={this.state.item.firstname} lastname={this.state.item.lastname}/>
        <City city={this.state.item.city}/></div>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger buttondelete" onClick={this.delete}>Delete</button>
      </div>
      </div>)
  }
}
```

When I delete a user, the state.items of Json update accordingly to the deletion, but the Cards are not re-rendered accordingly. In fact, the props are passed to the cards, but it is always the last one which is removed from the view, whereas a console.log shows that everything is fine...

Comment: Try passing key while using map to render

Comment: Best practice is to pass down delete method as props from parent to the child component, then convert the child component into a purely functional component. State can be easier managed this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem in rendering of array of components without a `key` property.

When you render an array of components in React, like here:

`{this.state.items.map(item => <Card item={item} updateJson={this.updateDelete}/>)}`

you need to specify a unique `key` property for every item. It will helps React to know which element is changed and should be rerendered.

For example:

`{this.state.items.map((item, index) => <Card key={'card-' + index} item={item} updateJson={this.updateDelete}/>)}`

Read this article [lists-and-keys.html](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: Thanks ! I created keys with shortid :) And I moved the frond and the back generations in Json, and it works :D